# Can't use a crt certificate

Tags: ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to use a certificate without success. I'm using it like this:

```
r = requests.get('https://server:8443/teste', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('USER', 'PASSWORD'), verify='/home/path/certificate.crt')
```

and I got the error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='server', port=8443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /teste (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:590)'),))

However I'm able to use the certificate with curl(if this help identifying the problem):

curl -s --cacert /home/path/certificate.crt -u USER:PASSWORD https://server:8443/teste

Can you help me make this work with the certificate?

Comment: " certificate verify failed" this is more related to the client checking the server certificate and not the client certificate. Make sure that you have the server CA properly configured on the client side. Each application may use different trust stores hence differences in results between your code and `curl`.

Comment: Isn't requests the client side? Can you elaborate on how should I check where is the problem?

Comment: Yes, requests is client side, it gets the server certificate as part of the TLS handshake and then, by default, attempts to validate the server certificate based on its know list of CAs. Which CA is using your server certificate? Also have a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification. The `verify=` option has nothing to do with your own client certificate. The path there is the one of the CA needed to verify the server certificate.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: IMHO both the `cacert` argument in curl and the `verify` argument in python requests have the same purpose: to specify the local trust store - in this case likely containing only a single certificate. There is no client certificate involved in this question.

Comment: @metRo_: could you please provide more details regarding the contents of the `certificate.crt` file? With OpenSSL a certificate inside this file will only be considered at all if it is a CA certificate (basic constraints CA true). Also, the trust chain must end if a self-signed certificate (i.e. root certificate). Python requests  uses OpenSSL as backend while curl might use a different backend (see `curl --version`) and thus show a different behavior.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek this is what I get looking on chrome info: https://imgur.com/a/Yu8jea9

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the curl versuion output: 
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think it is a self-signed certificate

Comment: @metRo_: the edited output from the certificate viewer suggests that the server sends a certificate signed by some `ca-intermediate` - i.e. not a self-signed certificate. The question is now which certificate do you have in `certificate.crt` and how this relates to the certificate sent by the server and how it relates to the root certificate of the trust chain. And, as you can see your curl is using GnuTLS not OpenSSL which might explain the difference in behavior compared to OpenSSL based requests.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how can I know which certificate do I have in certificate.crt?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "There is no client certificate involved in this question." I kind of agree but "I'm trying to use a certificate without success." in the question may also have been used by someone wanting to use a client certificate (it is rare to write you "use" a CA/intermediate certificate), so it was not absolutely clear to me in which case we were, hence my comment. Anyway, seeing the real name involved and the certificate content would make troubleshooting easier...

Comment: @metRo_: I would imagine that you have put a specific certificate on purpose into `certificate.crt` and knew which one you've used. If not use `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text` to show the first one in the file. If there are multiple certificates in the file see [How to view all ssl certificates in a bundle?](https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I choose this certificate.crt because it is the one that the IT team of my company make available to use with chrome or other browser to access internal services.

Comment: @metRo_: while your last comment says where you got the certificate from it says nothing what the certificate is for. If the certificate is only the server certificate (which is not self-signed as the output from Chrome shows) then this is not sufficient for validation with OpenSSL - one need to have the root CA instead and all intermediate certificates which are not sent by the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich instead of remove the info from the screenshot I change my companyname so you can see all the details if it help